# Find $\int t\sin^{-1}t\hspace{1mm}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find $\int t\sin^{-1}t\hspace{1mm}dt$

How do we approach this question, is there a simple way to integrate

Comment: Is $\sin^{-1}$ meant as the arcsine or the secant? In other words, functional inverse or algebraic inverse?

Comment: functional inverse

Answer (score 1):

1. **Proper substitution:** Draw the right triangle with one side being $t$ and a hypotenuse of $1$, the other side is then $\sqrt{1-t^{2}}$. Now substitute: 
   $$\theta =Sin^{-1}(t)\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta }{\mathrm{d} t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\Rightarrow dt=\sqrt{1-t^{2}}d\theta =Cos(\theta )d\theta $$

   $$\int tSin^{-1}(t)dt=\int \theta Sin(\theta )Cos(\theta )d\theta $$
2. **Integration by Parts:** 
   $$u=\theta , dv=Sin(\theta )Cos(\theta )d\theta $$
   $$du=d\theta , v=\frac{1}{2}Sin^{2}(\theta )$$

The rest is easy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\sin^{-1}t,\; dv=t dt$, so $\;du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt, \;v=\frac{t^2}{2}$.

Then $\displaystyle\int t\sin^{-1}t \;dt=\frac{t^2}{2}\sin^{-1}t-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt$.

Now let $t=\sin\theta, dt=\cos\theta d\theta$ to get $\displaystyle\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt=\int\sin^{2}\theta d\theta$,

and then use a half-angle formula to simplify the integrand.